# AWS Elastic Beanstalk with PHP 8.0 (64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.15) more than 2 mb file uploads are stopped suddenly

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The application was developed in Laravel 8, One of my client applications suddenly stopped uploading more than 2 MB of files. I have checked the Nginx configuration is fine.

The client_max_body_size value is 50M.

I have used this structure to update the configuration "platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf file"

And also applied the Nginx reload too.